# Is there a way to use an input to select a class member variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do the following where I use an input variable number to select an object in a class. Is there a way to do this in Python? I'm thinking of how you can do something similar with strings in python. with print(f"Hello World {some_variable}")

```
class thing():
  obj1 = 1
  obj2 = 2
  obj3 = 3


def(thing_class, number):
  thing_class.obj{number} = 10
```

Comment: Make it a dictionary with string keys like `{"obj1":1...` and pass a string in the function?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `setattr`, something like:

```py
class Thing:
    obj1 = 1
    obj2 = 2
    obj3 = 3

def thing_setter(thing_class, number, value):
    # sets the attribute selected by the string to value
    setattr(thing_class, f"obj{number}", value)
```

Test:

```py
>>> my_thing = Thing()
>>> my_thing.obj1
1
>>> thing_setter(my_thing, 1, 10)
>>> my_thing.obj1
10
```